Next js api not working after deployment | API call 504 error deployed on vercel just an ai image generator application
I have build an interior ai application
after login going to dashboard and creating a new design selecting all the features i get some 504 error.
It works seamlessly when done locally but after it is deployed on vercel I don't know what the issue is:
const GenerateAiImage = async () => {
  console.time("API Processing Time");

  // Start loading
  setLoading(true);

  try {
    // Save raw image to Firebase and get the URL
    const rawimageUrl = await SaveRawImageToFirebase();

    // Post request to the redesign-room API
    const result = await axios.post(
      "/api/redesign-room",
      {
        imageUrl: rawimageUrl,
        roomType: formData?.roomType,
        designType: formData?.designType,
        additional: formData?.additional,
        userEmail: user?.primaryEmailAddress?.emailAddress,
      },
      {
        timeout: 60000,
      }
    );

    // Handle the result
    console.log(result);
    setAIOutput(result.data.result);

    // Update credits and open the output dialog
    updateUserCredits();
    setOpenOutputDialog(true);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error handling
    console.error("Error generating AI image:", error);

    // Optionally, set an error message to display to the user
    alert(
      "There was an error processing your request. Please try again later."
    );
  } finally {
    // Stop loading (even if there was an error)
    setLoading(false);
  }

  console.timeEnd("API Processing Time");
};


generate image call from the api
export async function POST(req) {
  // const { user } = useUser();
  const { imageUrl, roomType, designType, additional, userEmail } =
    await req.json();
  try {
    const imageBlob = await getImageAsBlob(imageUrl);
    const result = await client.predict("/mlsd", {
      image: imageBlob,
      prompt: "A " + roomType + " with a " + designType + " style interior",
      additional_prompt: additional,
    });
    console.log(result.data);
    const output = result.data[0][1].image.url;
    console.log("Fetching and converting image...", output);
    const base64imageUrl = await ConvertImageToBase64(output);

    if (!base64imageUrl.startsWith("data:image/png;base64,")) {
      throw new Error("Base64 conversion failed or returned invalid data.");
    }

    console.log("Uploading to Firebase...");
    const fileName = Date.now() + ".png";
    const storageRef = ref(storage, "interior-ai/" + fileName);
    await uploadString(storageRef, base64imageUrl, "data_url");

    console.log("Fetching download URL...");
    const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

    console.log("File uploaded successfully:", downloadUrl);
    // return NextResponse.json({ result: downloadUrl });
    const dbResult = await db
      .insert(AiGeneratedImage)
      .values({
        roomType: roomType,
        designType: designType,
        orgImg: imageUrl,
        aiImage: downloadUrl,
        userEmail: userEmail,
      })
      .returning({ id: AiGeneratedImage.id });
    console.log(dbResult);

    return NextResponse.json({ result: downloadUrl });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in POST handler:", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message });
  }
}


this is the api route.jsx with other functions too
The error I am getting is 504 request timeout but i have increased the timeout limit also still after 1 second itself it shows the error.
I wanted it to process and show up the image.
